# How to restrict directory creation to trunk, tags, branches with a pre-commit hook in SVN?

Tags: regex, svn, tortoisesvn, pre-commit-hook

Current setup:

We have approximately 7 repositories in our SVN instance. Each repository has multiple      applications, and each application should have a trunk, tags, and branches directory (nothing    else)!

EG:

```
 REPOSITORY-1
  --> APP-1
      --> trunk
      --> tags
      --> branches
  --> APP-2
      --> trunk
      --> tags
      --> branches
```

Overtime I have noticed developers deviating from this process and creating all kinds of directories. For example:

```
 REPOSITORY-1
   --> APP-1
       --> src
       --> READ-ME.txt
   --> APP-2
       --> build
       --> random-file.java
       --> build.xml
```

Is there a way to have a hook with a patter that restricts the pattern to reject any commits that try to create any files or directories other than trunk, tags, and branches under the application? Thank you in advance for any help!

Extra info: Our SVN server is on a RedHat box.

Answer (score 1):

**Add the below script in pre-commit to restrict the directory creation:**

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"
DIRCHAR="/"
SVNLOOK=/opt/csvn/bin/svnlook
echo $($SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | awk '{print $2}') > /tmp/files_$TXN.txt
sed -i 's/ /&\n/g' /tmp/files_$TXN.txt
while read line
do
LASTCHAR=`echo $line | awk '{print substr($0,length,1)}'`
if [ "$LASTCHAR" == "$DIRCHAR" ]; then
    echo -e "Cannot commit directory." 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
done < /tmp/files_$TXN.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform in pre-commit hook `svnlook dirs-changed REPOS_PATH` and check output ( | grep -v ...)